# onBindViewHolder not called until scroll

Tags: android, statusbar

I'm using this lib https://github.com/fede87/StatusBarAlert to show a message on the status bar.

The problem is: this lib is causing a problem in my `RecyclerView`.

I don't know why, but even if I call `setAdapter`, the `onBindViewHolder` is not called until I scroll the empty recycle.

I tried to remove the message, and my recycle works great.

But I want to know why this is happening.

Any of you guys know about it?

**EDIT**

I've removed the StatusBarAlert call and I called Snackbar instead. Now, my Recyclerview is working fine again.

The question is: what inside https://github.com/fede87/StatusBarAlert  is making this recyclerview problem?

I dont see nothing special, looking the lib's source code

Comment: Onbindviewholder will be called only if there are items to display, with empty, there will not be anything to bind. And I understand what you mean by scroll the empty recyclerview.

Comment: It could be linked to the view added by the library, which *could* be interpreted by Android as an overlaying view, which doesn't allow the adapter to bind data to his view holders, because technically the children aren't shown. Can you post your code?

Comment: @Dinash I know it. The fact that its working okay when I dont call the StatusBarMessage its the point. Maybe the way that lib works, putting a new view in the `decorView`, translucent flag, etc is letting the RecyclerView a little crazy?

Comment: @GiuseppeGiacoppo I'll edit my question with some code, but its basically I call the StatusBarView and after that I call setAdapter. If I remove StatusBarView, works.

Comment: Well, I've removed the StatusBarView and called Snackbar instead. After that, my `RecyclerView` its working fine again.